# Highlight cell in first column for resulting/winning highlighted cell

Tags: javascript, html, css

Please view my code on jsfiddle as I can't seem to figure out how to post on here.
After "Click to Draw a Winner" button is pressed, 10 seconds later, a winner is determined. However, only the winners ballot number is highlighted.

**What needs to be added to highlight the corresponding winning ballots Rep name?**

https://jsfiddle.net/Nick_Chand/tymv6m03/

```
<div class="container">
```

```
<table style="width: 100%; height: 100%; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="width: 50%; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;" rowspan="2">
        <button class="choosewinner" style="text-align: center; font-weight: bold; font-size: 18px;">Click to Draw a Winner</button>
      </td>
      <td align="center;" style="text-align: center; font-size: 16px; font-weight: bold;">WIN A PRIZE OF $</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="width: 50%; text-align: center; font-weight: bold; color: #E63946">Qualifying Reps - Prize Number 1</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<table id="table_id" class="table text-center">


  <tbody class="row" style="font-size: 12px; ">

    <table class="tableizer-table" >
      <thead>
        <tr class="tableizer-firstrow">
          <th style="text-align: center;">_______Rep_______</th>
          <th style="text-align: center;">_Ballots_</th>
          <th style="text-align: center;">_Probability_</th>
          <th style="text-align: center;">1</th>
          <th style="text-align: center;">2</th>
          <th style="text-align: center;">3</th>
          <th style="text-align: center;">4</th>
          <th style="text-align: center;">5</th>
          <th style="text-align: center;">6</th>
          <th style="text-align: center;">7</th>
          <th style="text-align: center;">8</th>
          <th style="text-align: center;">9</th>
          <th style="text-align: center;">10</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody align=center>
```

A.B.50.26%    1    2    3    4    5
D.K60.31% 1    2    3    4    5    6
T.R90.47% 1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9
G.J30.16% 1    2    3

Comment: do mark the answer correct if it worked for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$(".choosewinner").click(function() {
  //highlight();
  var startTime = new Date().getTime();
  var interval = setInterval(function() {
    if (new Date().getTime() - startTime > 10000) {
      clearInterval(interval);
      $('.highlight').addClass('youwin');
      **$('.highlight').parent().children(':first-child').addClass('youwin');**
      return;
    }
    highlight();
  }, 200);
});
```

Comment: @NickChand Can you please accept it as correct answer then?

Answer (score 1):

Add this code to highlight the Name

```
$('.highlight').addClass('youwin').parent().find('td:first-child').addClass('youwin');
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi Just add this to your script:

```
$(".choosewinner").click(function() {
  //highlight();
  var startTime = new Date().getTime();
  var interval = setInterval(function() {
    if (new Date().getTime() - startTime > 2000) {
      clearInterval(interval);
      $('.highlight').addClass('youwin');

            HilightWinner($('.highlight'));  // NEW LINE

            return;
    }
    highlight();
  }, 200);
});

// NEW FUNCITON
function HilightWinner(myDiv){
    if(myDiv){
        var td = $('td:first', myDiv.parents('tr'));
        td.addClass('youwin');
    }
}
```